# Loss function for neural network to reduce false positives

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, loss-functions, false-discovery-rate

I am trying to train a network to keep false positive as low as possible. I do not mind if I don't have extremely high accuracy, but I want the false positives to be within 5%.

Are there any existing loss functions that reduce the false-positives at the cost of overall accuracy ?

I am currently weighted sum of True positives and False positives as the metric. Is there some metric specifically for this task.

How would I go about achieving this notion? I've searched everywhere and can't find any literature on this